# Как задать условие в Enum'e в Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, enum

Имеется enum:

```java
public enum CommandType {
    LOGIN(new SignInCommand()),
    LOGOUT(new LogoutCommand());

    private Command command;

    CommandType(Command command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public Command getCommand() {
        return this.command;
    }
}
```

И я хочу с помощью стрима проверить, имеется ли данный enum и вернуть `Optional.empty()` в случае его отсутствия. Делаю это так:

```java
return Arrays.stream(CommandType.values())
                .filter(type -> type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(requestCommand))
                .findFirst()
                .map(CommandType::getCommand);
```

Вопрос: как в данном способе вернуть `Optional.empty`, если будет передано значение в переменную `requestCommand`, отсутствующее в `enum'e`?

Насколько мне известно, `findFirst()` возвращает первый элемент из стрима (возвращает Optional).
Пробовал так, но это не верно:

```java
return Arrays.stream(CommandType.values())
                .filter(type -> type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(requestCommand))
                .findFirst()
                .map(CommandType::getCommand)
                .orElse(Optional.empty());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findFirst` превращает stream в Optional. Так что либо делайте сначала `map`, а уже потом `findFirst`:

```
return Arrays.stream(CommandType.values())
                .filter(type -> type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(requestCommand))
                .map(CommandType::getCommand)
                .findFirst()
;
```

Либо используйте `Optional.flatMap`, чтоб преобразовать значение, если оно есть:

```
return Arrays.stream(CommandType.values())
                .filter(type -> type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(requestCommand))
                .findFirst()
                .flatMap(CommandType::getCommand);
```

Comment: На второй вариант выдает ошибку:
`reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that Command conforms to Optional<? extends U>`.